# iOS How to hide double values in UITableView row

Tags: ios, sqlite, uitableview, uilabel, touchxml

I am busy with an application where I show a list of events in a TableView. Per row/cell I have an event showing the title of the event and the date. The problem now is that when there are 2 or more events on one day the app now shows them nicely per cell but the user will see the date 2 or more times repeatedly, which looks inefficient and kinda redundant. So my thought was to check wether the previous cell date is similar to the current cell date and this would make the current cell date hidden (I cannot remove it completely, cause the user is able to save the event into the calendar).

I am reading an external XML into a SQLite database via TouchXML.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
-(void) grabXMLData:(NSString *)dataAddress {

    _managedObjectContext = [(DAFAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: dataAddress];
    CXMLDocument *xmlParser = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:nil];

    NSArray *resultNodes = NULL;
    resultNodes = [xmlParser nodesForXPath:@"//month" error:nil];

    for (CXMLElement *resultElement in resultNodes) {
        NSMutableDictionary *monthItem = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        [monthItem setObject:[[resultElement attributeForName:@"name"] stringValue] forKey:@"name"];
        [monthItem setObject:[[resultElement attributeForName:@"month"] stringValue] forKey:@"month"];
        [monthItem setObject:[[resultElement attributeForName:@"year"] stringValue] forKey:@"year"];

        Month *aMonth = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Month" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
        aMonth.name =  [monthItem objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        aMonth.month = [f numberFromString:[monthItem objectForKey:@"month"]];
        aMonth.year = [f numberFromString:[monthItem objectForKey:@"year"]];

        NSArray *itemNodes = [resultElement children];

        for (CXMLElement *resultItem in itemNodes) {
            NSMutableDictionary *item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            [item setObject:[[resultItem attributeForName:@"id"] stringValue] forKey:@"id"];

            int counter;
            for(counter = 0; counter < [resultItem childCount]; counter++) {
                [item setObject:[[resultItem childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:[[resultItem childAtIndex:counter] name]];

            }

            Item *aItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
            NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
            aItem.nr = [f numberFromString:[item objectForKey:@"id"]];
            aItem.title = [item objectForKey:@"title"];
            aItem.body = [item objectForKey:@"body"];
            aItem.date = [item objectForKey:@"date"];
            aItem.start = [item objectForKey:@"start"];
            aItem.end = [item objectForKey:@"end"];
        aItem.start2 = [item objectForKey:@"start2"];
            aItem.end2 = [item objectForKey:@"end2"];
            aItem.link_url = [item objectForKey:@"link_url"];
            aItem.month = aMonth;
            [aMonth addItemObject:aItem];
        }
    }
}
```

It is the item date that needs to be compared.

This is part of my tableview cellForRowAtIndex code:

```
Month *aMonth = [_stages objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorItem = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"nr" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: sortDescriptorItem, nil];
    _stagesPerMonth = [[aMonth.item allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    Item *aItem = [_stagesPerMonth objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. You can use the hidden property of the label to hide it, and you should make sure that the data of the previous row is available when the next row is processed.

Comment: Oh, and I suggest you use the shorthands for handling arrays and dictionaries that were introduced recently in Obj-C. Provided you can. They make your code a lot more readable.

Comment: What I want to do is hide the label with the date information if on the previous row the date label has the same value. I am kinda stuck and code blind at the moment and have no clue how to realize this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you use a custom cell that has a label for displaying the date. A pseudo code for `cellForRowAtIndex` would be:

```
Item *aItem = [_stagesPerMonth objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSDate thisDate = aItem.date;

// Obtain the date of the previous event or nil if this is the first event
NSDate prevDate = indexPath.row > 0 ? _stagesPeMonth[indexPath.row - 1].date : nil;

// Date label is hidden if the previous date is the same as this.
dateLabel.hidden = [thisDate isEqualToDate: prevDate];
```

The syntax may be different in your case.

Comment: many thanks for you effort already. I have implemented the code and there is one error. For the sentence: `NSDate prevDate = indexPath.row > 0 ? _stagesPerMonth[indexPath.row - 1].date : nil;` The error (Property date not found on object of type id) becomes visible.
Do you have any idea what might go wrong?

Comment: In your first snippet you write: `aItem.date = [item objectForKey:@"date"]` If the `Item` in the second snippet is the same type as in the first one, then then there must be a date property on it. Otherwise, this is why I indicated that the syntax can be different in your case. Try to change your code to implement the logic described in the comments in my code.